# Configure coverage lcov file from pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

When using `pytest` with the `pytest-cov` plugin, I am able to use the ***pyconfig.toml*** file to set the required options.

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "-p no:cacheprovider --cov --no-cov-on-fail"
enable_assertion_pass_hook = true
python_files = "tests/*_test.py"

[tool.coverage.run]
branch = true
data_file = ".coverage/.coverage"
source = ["wwaz/assets"]

[tool.coverage.report]
fail_under = 95
show_missing = true
```

However, I now wish to output an ***lcov*** file, but the `lcov output` option isn't working, with no file being output. I've reviewed the [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#lcov) and as far as I can see, this is how that option should be specified.

```ini
[tool.coverage.lcov]
output = ".coverage/.lcov"
```